# How to make Dynamic String with this Keyword

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call this function on click but I need to call this function `this.handlingRecursiveTable(arg1, arg2)` like this... but when I use `this` gives me an error.

if I using like this... this gives me TypeError but I need to call the function with `this` keyword.

```
 recursiveTable  +=  "<td><input type='button' value='Show Data' onclick='this.handlingRecursiveTable("+stringifyData+", \""+newId+"\")'></td>"
```

How to make this Dynamic String with `this` Keyword.

My Whole code is

```
supportedKey = (key) =>{
    var newkey ="";
      for(i=1; i<key.length; i++){
          if(key.charCodeAt(i)>=65 && key.charCodeAt(i)<=90){
              newkey = newkey + " " + key[i];
          }else newkey = newkey + key[i];
      }
      return key[0].toUpperCase() + newkey
    }




    var str = '';
    handlingRecursiveTable = (arrayOfData, newId)=>{


       var qqqq = document.getElementById(newId)
       if(qqqq==null){ 

        var zz = newId;
        var a = newId.indexOf("*");
            a = newId.substring(0, a);
        var table =  document.getElementById(a);

        var recursiveTable = '';
        recursiveTable +=   "<table id="+zz+" border = '1'>" + '<tr>';

        for(let key in arrayOfData){
            for(let keyAgain in arrayOfData[key]){
                     recursiveTable +=  '<th>' + supportedKey(keyAgain) + '</th>';
            }
        }

        recursiveTable +=  '</tr><tr>';

        for(let key in arrayOfData){
           for(let keyAgain in arrayOfData[key]){

               if(Array.isArray(arrayOfData[key][keyAgain])){
                 var stringifyData = JSON.stringify(arrayOfData[key][keyAgain]);
                 newId = newId + 's';
                 recursiveTable  +=  "<td><input type='button' value='Show Data' onclick='this.handlingRecursiveTable("+stringifyData+", \""+newId+"\")'></td>"
               }else{
                    recursiveTable +=  '<td>' + arrayOfData[key][keyAgain] + '</td>';
               }
           }
       }

        recursiveTable  +=  '</tr>'  + "</table border = '1'>"
        table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML + recursiveTable;
       }

       else{
           console.log('pahle')
       }
    }
    
    



    renderData = (user) =>{
        var data = document.getElementById('data')
        for(let key in user){
             if (Array.isArray(user[key])){
                data.innerHTML = data.innerHTML + '<p>'+supportedKey(key) +'-------</p>'
                data.innerHTML = data.innerHTML + '<div id= '+str+'s'+'></div>'
                handlingRecursiveTable(user[key], str + 's' + '*')
                str= str + 's';
             }else{
                 data.innerHTML = data.innerHTML + '<p>'+supportedKey(key) +'-------' + user[key] + '</p>'
             }
        }
    }
    
    const user = {
        
        "nodeOne": [
        {"shikharJindal": "06/07/2020Jindal"},
        {"mohitSindalJindal": 1231234567890},
        {"elementSeven": [
            {"qqqqUip": "06/07/2020Jindal"},
            {"ssssDip": [
                {"new1": "Newwwwwwww111"},
                {"new2": "neeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"}]
            },
        ]}
        ],  
        "nodeTwo": "05/06/2020",
        "nodeThree": 777,
        "nodeFour": [
            {"elementOne": "B Street"},
            {"elementTwo": "City"},
            {"elementThree": "Area - 591323"},
            {"elementFour": [
                {"elementFive": "06/07/2020"},
                {"elementSix": 123},
                {"elementSeven": [
                    {"qqqqUip": "06/07/2020Jindal"},
                    {"ssssDip": 1231234567890}
                ]},
            ]}
        ],
        "nodeFive" : "shubham Jindalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    }
    
   renderData(user);
```

Comment: Do `handlingRecursiveTable(this, "+stringifyData+", \""+newId+"\")` instead of doing `this.handlingRecursiveTable("+stringifyData+", \""+newId+"\")`

Comment: but I need to use **this** keyword for calling the function ...without **this** function not working

Comment: It would be helpful, if we could see the handlingRecursiveTable function as well

Comment: I edited my post ..please have a look at  code

Answer (score 1):

`this` in an `onclick` attribute of a button will be *the button* and not whatever object you are dealing with in the function that the line of code you shared appears in.

Do not try to generate JavaScript embedded in HTML by mashing strings together in JavaScript.

- It is hard to read
- It is hard to debug
- It runs in a different scope
- It is easy to make errors by failing to property escape data

Use DOM methods instead.

```
const td = document.createElement("td");
const button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button";
button.value = "Show Data";
button.addEventListener("click", event => this.handlingRecursiveTable(stringifyData, newId));
td.appendChild(button);
tr.appendChild(td); // Define tr first
```

Comment: Actually my whole code is based on embedded  HTML in JavaScript .... if I change this...then need to change the whole component...

Comment: It *might* be possible to hack things to put whatever `this` in a variable in the global scope, and make sure that each `onclick` attribute gets a reference to the right thing for `this` … but that's adding even more complexity and likelihood of it going wrong … and your code is *already* in a state where you couldn't solve the problem by yourself. You really should refactor the component to take a more sensible and easier to manage approach.

Comment: @ShubhamJindal i'd definitively follow this advice. You think you save some time now fixing this issue but many more will come later as Quentin says